# Capture the microphone on safari and iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, getusermedia

On a PC you can easily capture the microphone within a google chrome or firefox browser with getUserMedia.
To my knowledge, this was so far not possible (also away from getusermedia) on apple devices. Is there now also a possibility to capture the microphone with Apple devices and safari using e.g. jquery/javascript.

Comment: afaik, still "no", having looked into it recently, but i sure wouldn't mind being wrong...

Answer (score 4):

As of iOs 11 getUserMedia() is supported :D

Comment: Yes but for FFT analysis you are limited to 2048 frequency bins which is the old standard as opposed to 32768 (latest standard) AND there is NO support in a standalone mobile web app AND even if there was, a standalone web app does not show up on the web inspector so you have to debug with alert()

Comment: @KerryDavis With "standalone mobile web app" You mean when it's added to homescreen?

Comment: yes <meta id="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" > AKA added to home screen as a web app

Answer (score 3):

Accessing audio and video devices in browser was only possible with the most popular getUserMedia/Stream API of WebRTC API in HTML 5.

As of today (May, 2017), safari does not support this API.
Check [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=getUserMedia%60) for references.

So it is quite difficult to access microphone in Safari on iOS. Even if u visit translate.google.com via Safari and any other browser(Chrome for example!) you will find microphone absent for Safari.

Comment: What if i open the same page in chrome in iPad or iPhone?